# Pay Pal - how to get button id

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have created button on pay pal and implement it on my site. 
How can I get that button ID?
It should be number that I can find in variable `btn_id` in payment response.

Comment: Payment response using [PayPal's IPN](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNReference)?

Comment: When I receive payment (IPN message) I get button ID its number like '31298766' but I can't find it on pay pal. I wan't to know this ID before payment.

Comment: Are you looking for the ID associated with the transaction on PayPal or the ID of the hosted button?

Comment: Use the BMButtonSearch API to get a list of all your stored hosted buttons, or BMGetButtonDetails to get the details of a specific button.